# Why is Bowser OK when he's not kidnapping the princess?

Tags: mario-series

Has it ever been touched on why everybody is alright with Bowser between his kidnappings?

I mean, the guy kidnapped the Princess multiple times, but when the princess is not kidnapped, they have parties, go Go-Karting and play every sport possible with him.

So was it ever touched upon why everybody is OK with Bowser being there when the guy has kidnapped the Princess multiple times?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236004/was-super-mario-bros-3-all-just-a-performance

Comment: Reminder: lore questions are NOT "game design and development"

Comment: Any game design questions would be in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ anyway<

Comment: Lore questions *most definitely* are game design questions. They just happen to be an on-topic area, for the most part. That said, playing poke the plot hole is utterly useless, and should be downvoted on that alone.

Comment: Well Bowser is still portrayed as the villain in most of those games so are they really just ignoring his villainy and past crimes?  I think not.  Mario Party is the best example of that; Bowser is there causing a villainous ruckus to ruin the party.  It's also worth keeping in mind that he's a giant turtle monster so you try arresting him or putting him in jail.  Then you also have to wonder, does the Mushroom Kingdom even have a police force to call to take Bowser away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common theory is that the characters in the Mario series are all actors and that the main series game are all stage plays or films, which is why the "actors" are frequently seen go-karting or playing sports together in the side games.